# Starting node http server at any free port

Tags: node.js, highcharts, node-modules

I am trying to start multiple highchart export servers via C# in a single windows machine.  Highchart export server is run as node http server. All node servers are started from different non communicating applications running in a single machine. I am starting the process from c# code like this.

```
Process process = new Process { command line arguments to start node server with port };
process.Start();
```

How can I specify non conflicting ports in C# code so that node servers can be started in each application ?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js can help you, use c# no problem.

You will need just to check port before you use it. If port is used you can't use that port this is basic rule for TCP/IP.

Take a look here : 
[NodeJS pinging ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723393/nodejs-pinging-ports)

Also npm have some app for port checking.
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcp-ping

Port is just a number you can use it on your will but would be better to follow standards. You can use 80 or 21 if port are free .

Comment: I want to specify the port in c# since i need to return the  port at which node server started. Multiple applications might start at same time so two applications might find the same port free before starting and try to connect . eventually one of them will fail and try to connect again. I do not want this situation to happen

Comment: Did you try it to test it ! There is no way to open two servers on same port ( on one computer - access point). If you can catch 'port already open' use than error like indicator !

Comment: Yes, 2 servers can not start on same port. I want each application to be able to find out a free port and start a server there without locking involved . I can definitely catch the exception if port is already is use and retry to connect on on another port . But I want to specify ports in applications such that no two aplications may try to start the server at same port